# On the definition of Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In Royden's 'Real Analysis', he first defines the Lebesgue integral of simple functions that vanish outside a set of finite measure and then extends this to non-negative bounded measurable functions that vanish outside a set of finite measure.  But in Rudin's 'Real and Complex Analysis', he straightaway defines the integral of a non-negative function as the limit of integrals of simple functions. He does not include any finite measure support considerations. My question is, what is the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: It is not necessary to consider the special case first. You c an define integrals for all non-negative simple functions and extend it to all non-negative  measurable functions without worrying about finiteness of the integrals. Rudin's approach is more standard.

Answer (score 1):

*I wanted to put it as a comment, but I didn't have enough place*.

A characteristic function $1_A$ is integrable $\iff$ $m(A)<\infty $.

So, probably in Rudin, they suppose that a simple function is defined as $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i 1_{A_i}$$ where $m(A_i)<\infty $, whereas in Royden, they define a simple function as $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i1_{A_i}$$ without assumption that $A_i$ have finite measure.

Comment: Wrong. Rudin does not require $m(A_i) <\infty$. See  my comment above.

Comment: @KaboMurphy: No problem, I will erase my comment then. I don't know this book, so it was just a (possible) explanation